# CoreData object modeling with multiple timeframes for weather data

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, ios7, relational-database

I do have some JSON file http://jsonblob.com/530664b3e4b0237f7f82bdfa I am pulling from forecast.io.

I am little confused how I should be creating my CoreData entities and relationships.

In below setup, I made my Location entity as the parent entity and created a separate entity for Currently, Minutely, Hourly, Daily. However I have decided it's best to hold all the information regarding the weather data in one entity, so I created a Data table for that purpose and tied it to Daily and Currently in the image below.

Before going further, I paused and would like to get a second opinion on it. Is this a valid way of going forward with this?

[image]

EDIT: Based on Wain's response I changed my model to this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `Minutely` and `Hourly` add little value as they don't have any attributes or relationships. It's also generally easier to add a `type` attribute rather than having a number of sub entities because you can easily filter the `type` using a predicate while doing a fetch. If you're going to add more in the future then there could be a case for keeping sub entities.

Once the entities are trimmed down then you only have a `Location` and `Data` with a relationship. You should make that relationship bi-directional so that Core Data can manage the data store contents better. (this applies to all relationships, even if you keep the sub entities you already have).

Other than that, fine :-)

Comment: Hi Wain, Thank you for prompt response :) I updated my screenshot to provide the final attributes based on the JSON result. Question 1: When you said "when you are going to add more in the future then there could be a case", do you mean adding more timeframes?

Comment: No, I meant adding more attributes. If all `Location` sub entities are going to have a relationship to `data` then you should move it to the `Location` entity (and really add an inverse relationship). Based on your current model content, I would just have `Location` and `Data` entities...

Comment: So to make sure I understand you correctly I will have two entities, Location and Data, and in the data I will additionally have a type attribute which will have the time frame and when I am fetching the data from this table later, I can just predicate based on the timeframe I ask (say currently, or hourly). correct?

Comment: `type` would go in `Location` (as a replacement for all the sub entities). And I also expect the relationship should be 1 `Location` to many `Data`. Consider looking at RestKit as well, it can help you with mapping the JSON to your model.

Comment: Always fun to iterate on the idea. Looking more closely at the JSON, I'd go for 3 entities actually. `Location`, `TimeBox` (with `type`, `icon`, `summary`) and `Data`. 1:many between `Location` and `TimeBox`. 1:many between `TimeBox` and `Data`. Each location has many time boxes, each of which has many data points.

Comment: Wain, again thanks a lot for your patience. I am currently following a RestKit tutorial (http://blog.alexedge.co.uk/introduction-to-restkit-0-20/) and trying to apply it to my project. Why would you bring a third entity (TimeBox)? For ease of accessing the summary of summary and icons?

Comment: Hi Wain, I updated my model picture above, please let me know if you see anything harmful in that picture :) Much appreciated.